# What does '# => ' represent in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

When working with Ruby on Rails in TextMate. I indent my multi-line comments like so

```
# This is a long comment and it'll run multiple lines so I'll
#   indent the second line so people know it's part of the first comment.
```

In TextMate's Ruby bundle when you type a hash then hit tab it auto generates the following

```
# => This text is still treated as a comment.
```

What is the significance of the `=>` symbol when used after a hash? Thanks!

Comment: `#` is not a hashtag. It is a hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a convention among Ruby users to represent the return value of an expression. TextMate adopted this convention.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response. Should we always use this convention when describing the return value of a variable/expression/method?

Comment: And the reason is because that's the way IRb displays the value of the last evaluated expression.

Comment: It's used throughout the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org), too. Putting a `#` in front of `=>` separates the return value from your code - it's still valid Ruby (you can copy and paste it) and it is highlighted as a comment.